# Should django-admin version be same as Django?

Tags: python, django, linux, django-admin

I tried to configure my PC for  Django course , i have fresh Ubuntu 18.04  :

I followed all steps from the course :

I had newest python pre-installed, Python 3.6.5 so i went :

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

went ok, then :

```
pip3 install django==2.0.2 (version suggested by instructor)
```

that completed as well, then :

```
django-admin startproject wordcount
```

and that gave me error :

```
Command 'django-admin' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-django-common
```

So i tried to install this but it didn't help. so i checked web for answers and i found that i should do :

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

And after that i could use

```
django-admin startproject wordcount
```

and it created a project for me but i saw that some elements of default files are different from what i saw on course video so i check and :

```
django-admin --version
1.11.11
```

also django-admin --help

gives me message like this :

```
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

Any ideas what went wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: what's the output of `pip3 freeze -l`

Comment: @schwobaseggl   

astroid==1.6.5
Django==2.0.6
isort==4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==1.9.2
pytz==2018.4
six==1.11.0
wrapt==1.10.11

Comment: and `pip freeze -l`

Comment: @schwobaseggl i don't even have pip installed : Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

Comment: Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/. Your django-admin should be the same version as django, otherwise it means you've got different versions of django installed. Do use a virtualenv, can't emphasise enough how important that is if you're serious about developing in python/django.

Answer (score 0):

I see you struggle with this problem. I would recommend you to move to such thing as a `virtualenv` (or use `anaconda` for this task). This should solve a numerous other problems you've not ran across yet and this one especially.

Virtual environment allows you to create separate environment, with it's own packet set. Some IDEs (for example, pycharm) provide GUI for it's creation and management.

**Update 1:**

Thanks to @DhavalSavalia, of course there is also `pipenv` package, that is a more friendly `virtualenv` wrapper (unless you have some gui for `virtualenv`).

**Update 2:**

Also, I've noticed that you setting up django using apt. You probably shouldn't do that, because apt often contains old version of python packages. Use pip for as many packages as you can.

Comment: Also `pipenv`. It has better dependancies management and is easier to setup than `virtualenv`, IMO.

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pip3-installed packages aren't on the PATH for some reason. There's a few ways to fix this.

1. Add the pip3 installation location to your `$PATH`.
2. Force it to use the version of Django you installed via pip3:

   `$ python3 -m django.bin.django-admin startproject wordcount`
3. Use virtualenv or pipenv to create a "virtual" Python installation - complete with it's own Python version and set of libraries.